# need to measure time but i get variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, flask

Hi i am using a flask server to make face verification, but when i try to measure the time of execution i get

```
  File "/home/test/apifave/main.py", line 50, in page_red
    return(str(t2-t1))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 't2' referenced before assignment
```

here is my code:

```
@app.route('/enrollment', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def page_red():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        t1=time.time()
        params = request.get_json(force=False, silent=False, cache=True)
        print(params)
        encodes = pd.read_sql_table("Encodes", con=db.engine)
        id_num = len(encodes)
        encode_subj = functionist()
        encode_pd = encode_creation(encode_subj, id_num, params)
        row_to_write = list(encode_pd.loc[0])
        row_value_markers = ','.join(['?']*len(row_to_write))
        db.engine.execute("INSERT INTO Encodes VALUES (%s)"%row_value_markers, row_to_write) 
        t2=time.time()
    return(str(t2-t1))
```

I suspect that i need to define t1 and t2 outside the if, but don't know how to do it, any help would be grateful

edit:

if i put the return in side the if i get the next error

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

Comment: Put the `return` statement inside the `if`.

Comment: i have done it but i get another error, i put the error in the question

Comment: You need to return something else when the method is `GET`.

Comment: the main idea is that the GET returns the time

Comment: But you're only calculating the time when you do `POST`.

Comment: Do you want to do a `POST` that calculates the time, then a `GET` that retrieves the time?

Comment: If that's what you want, you need to save the time somewhere during the `POST` request, then fetch it in the next `GET` request. Maybe use session variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple:

```
@app.route('/enrollment', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def page_red():
    t1=time.time()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        params = request.get_json(force=False, silent=False, cache=True)
        print(params)
        encodes = pd.read_sql_table("Encodes", con=db.engine)
        id_num = len(encodes)
        encode_subj = functionist()
        encode_pd = encode_creation(encode_subj, id_num, params)
        row_to_write = list(encode_pd.loc[0])
        row_value_markers = ','.join(['?']*len(row_to_write))
        db.engine.execute("INSERT INTO Encodes VALUES (%s)"%row_value_markers, row_to_write) 

    t2=time.time()

    return(str(t2-t1))
```

The only problem with this method is if you get a 'GET' request sent to your method, the time result will be 0.

You may need an `else` clause to handle GET requests.